# find hash key for android facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, keytool

I have a certificate I generated using eclipse export.

How can I find the hash key from the certificate for the facebook hash key?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you need to generate the key hash with the release certificate, try something like this:

keytool -exportcert -keystore (your release certificate dir) | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Comment: U would think this would work, but it doesnt.  FB tells me to use another key, different from the one generated by the above command.  FB tells me the key to use as part of error response when trying to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

[Add your app's signature to the Facebook App Settings](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig)

Comment: using the following command, keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64, i get a key but it is not the right key.  The key is also private so I removed 'androiddebugkey' to see if it makes a difference, but it doesnt even though this also gives me different hash key

Comment: when you export the app you have to select a exiting keystore or to create a new one. you this keystore to create the hash key fpr facebook

Comment: that is the one i am using.  when facebook launches on my app it returns the correct key in the error message, but i dont know why it is different

Answer (score 0):

If you run your app without setting the hask key on Facebook, an error message in the logs will display the needed hash key.